# Updating parent page from dynamically loaded user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hosting page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LoadMyControl(Parameters);  //Do it every page load to preserve it's state           
}

protected void LoadMyControl(string parameters)
{
     plchld.Controls.Clear();

     Control userControl = LoadControl("TheUserControl.ascx");
     userControl.ID = "userControl1";       
     plchld.Controls.Add(userControl);
}
```

Now inside this control, when a button is clicked I want to update ,let's say a Label on the hosting page. 
What is the best way to do it? Custom event?

Answer (score 0):

Solution maybe:

In the parent page add:

```
    public Label Actions
{
    get { return _Actions; }
    set { _Actions = value; }
}
```

on User Control add the following to the top

```
<%@ Reference Page="../parentpage.aspx" %>
```

and to change the value just do the following in the user control

```
        ASP.parentpage cc = (ASP.parentpage)this.Parent.Page;
        cc.Actions.Text = "hello world";
```

Answer (score -1):

A UserControl has a `Page` property which is a reference to the page in which the control is added. You could either cast directly to the known page type that contains the label,
e.g.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var page = Page as _Default;
    if (page != null)
    {
        page.Label1.Text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

but what would probably be better, is that you decorate you pages where this control can be used with an interface:

```
public interface ILabelHost
{
    void SetLabel(string text);
}

public class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, ILabelHost
{
    ...
```

That way you can use that same logic from before, but on anypage the control is loaded and implements the correct interface:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var host = Page as ILabelHost;
    if (host != null)
    {
        host.SetLabel("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: When i tried to cast to my page type, i got error on page.Label1.Text: _Default.Label1' is inaccessible due to its protection level